# How to use serializer inside serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Now this is my plan:
I want to be able to show followers for users,but i have a problem.I have to use nested serializers to show serializers which gives me this error:

```
 followers_set= UserSerializer(source='followers',many=True)
NameError: name 'UserSerializer' is not defined
```

Now i am using this kind of modelling in my API:

**Models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser,PermissionsMixin):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    username =models.CharField(max_length=80,unique=True,default='SOME STRING')


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

class FollowUserModel(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='followers')
    profile = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

And here are my serializers:

**Serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    followers_set= UserSerializer(source='followers',many=True)


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields  = ('id','email','username','followers_set')
```

How can i modify it in a way that it shows serializers inside serializer??

Comment: Why are you trying to use `UserSerializer` on followers which are `FollowUserModel`s and not `User`s? Why not create a new serializer class for `FollowUserModel`s?

Comment: Because i am trying to get it as a full user model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`serializers.SerializerMethodField(...)`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) as

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    followers_set = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_followers_set(self, user):
        return UserSerializer(user.followers.all(), source='followers', many=True).data

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'username', 'followers_set')
```

Comment: TypeError: Object of type ListSerializer is not JSON serializable?

Comment: Fixed the typo, try now